# FFmpeg dshow device format list

Tags: ffmpeg, ffdshow

I would like to ask is there any option for getting dshow device format list on Windows.

For example on Linux I am able to get device format list on Linux via

```
v4l2-ctl -i /dev/video0 --list-formats

Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
Name        : YUV 4:2:2 (YUYV)

Index       : 1
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'H264' (compressed)
Name        : H.264

Index       : 2
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
Name        : MJPEG
```

On Windows, I am able to get device list

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

and device options

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="MY_DSHOW_DEVICE_NAME"
```

But I am not able to get format list, like on Linux via v4l2.

**How can I get supported format list for dshow device via FFmpeg on Windows?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A delayed answer to your question.

It is not possible to clearly understand what you mean by "format list", but if you refer to the `Pixel Format` that appears when using `v4l2`, then you can get this data from the output of the `-list_options` command that you mentioned.

On my laptop, for example, I have the following output when running `ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video ="Integrated Webcam"`:

(omitting the first lines for easy viewing)

```
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=960x540 fps=30 max s=960x540 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=960x540 fps=30 max s=960x540 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=848x480 fps=30 max s=848x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=848x480 fps=30 max s=848x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=30 max s=1280x720 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=30 max s=640x480 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=160x120 fps=30 max s=160x120 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x180 fps=30 max s=320x180 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x180 fps=30 max s=320x180 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=320x240 fps=30 max s=320x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=424x240 fps=30 max s=424x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=424x240 fps=30 max s=424x240 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x360 fps=30 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x360 fps=30 max s=640x360 fps=30
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=10
[dshow @ 000001cc91eea4c0]   pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=10
```

As you can see, the data contained in the `vcodec` and `pixel_format` keys are the same values that you would find in `v4l2`'s `Pixel Format`, in this case `mjpeg` and `yuyv422`, respectively.

If what you want is an output with the same text formatting as `v4l2`, then I understand that this can be addressed with regular expressions, for example, and it is not directly related to `FFmpeg`.